# Using Font-Awesome 4.7.0 in ExtJS 7.1.0

Tags: javascript, extjs, package, font-awesome, extjs7

ExtJS 7.1.0 is using Font-Awesome 5.6.3. But my App was build in ExtJS 6 and I have used a lot of icons from font-awesome 4 which are no longer available in version 5. My question now is, is it somehow possible to downgrade the font-awesome version?

I have already tried to replace the `/framework/font-awesome`  Folder but this throws an error on building. And  I have tried to create my own package in `/workspace/local/packages/font-awesome-470` according to this guide: https://jnesis.com/en/blog/how-to-take-advantage-of-font-awesome-5-in-your-ext-js-6-applications/

The guide explains how to upgrade from font-awesome 4 to 5. I thought it would also work the other way around. However I'm always getting a build error that looks like this:

```
[LOG] Fashion Error : Reference to undeclared variable : $fa_line_height_base :
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Fashion build exited with code : 1
[ERR]   at sun.reflect.N
[ERR] ativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 1 minute 38 seconds
```

Comment: wouldn't be simpler to [update](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4#name-changes) the references to the icons?

Comment: The icons are not exactly the same! For instance, file-pdf-o (search it here: https://fontawesome.com/v4/cheatsheet/) is not the same as file-pdf (https://fontawesome.com/v5/icons/file-pdf?s=solid&f=classic) which is solid. Whoever did the job of writing the update/upgrade process didn't pay attention to details such as how the icons look in the new version vs the old version.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a chance to try the "upgrade" procedure posted on the old Sencha forum?
It was written for Ext JS 6 but with a little work should work with 7.  Note the upgrade shows how to run two flavors of Font Awesome simultaneously.  In your case you'll be adding an older version.  [How to upgrade Font Awesome](https://forum.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?469569-How-to-upgrade-Font-Awesome).