# Integrate font-awesome pro 5 with ExtJs 7.6.0

Tags: extjs, font-awesome, font-awesome-5, extjs7-classic

ExtJs 7.6.0 comes with the free version of font-awesome (fa) 5. Has anyone been successful in integrating fa pro 5 with ExtJs 7.6.0 (classic)?

If yes, any tips or instructions?

I found these [instructions](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vTMeguHbys-u-s5xAjm6NbL31C67cFsdQGoJCt4EqrJ6RhQvtZO7qcZ6xqOMcb7xPy96wRQOk3-0Dvz/pub) from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68633277/using-font-awesome-4-7-0-in-extjs-7-1-0) but they apply to integrating fa 5 into ExtJs 6.6.0 which uses fa 4.7 by default.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully integrated both `Font Awesome Pro 5 and 6`, into `Ext JS versions 6 and 7 (classic)`. I used several guides, including the ones you linked, and last time I even got an upgrade instructions document from Sencha Support.

I can tell you, this is not an easy ride since both Ext JS and Font Awesome are changing constantly, every guide is somehow outdated, and even the document I got from Sencha Support was not complete. Many manual tweaks are needed to get it work.

So I can share the steps I followed last time (`Font Awesome Pro 6 - Ext JS 7.6`) but chances are good that you will need additional steps to get it work. All paths are relative to your project's root folder.

1. Back up existing FA (`ext/packages/font-awesome`).
2. Get the FA Pro (web) version you'd like (you need subscription for the Pro versions), and unzip it into `ext/packages/font-awesome/resources`.
3. From `webfonts` directory under the folder in the previous step, copy files to `ext/packages/font-awesome/resources/fonts`.
4. Examine the contents of the downloaded FA package in `scss` folder. You have to copy these files under `ext/packages/font-awesome/sass/etc`, but depending on the version, you might need to rename some files. For example in latest FA Pro it is `regular.scss` etc., but in `ext/packages/font-awesome/sass/etc` you need to have `fa-regular.scss`.

The following steps should be perfomed in `ext/packages/font-awesome/sass/etc`. Honestly I don't know if all of them are necessary, you can try without these or after every step to see how it works out.

**You always have to execute `sencha app build development` to test it and repeat it after every change.**

1. In `_core.scss` change `font-family: var(--#{$fa-css-prefix}-style-family, '#{$fa-style-family}');` to `font-family: var(--#{$fa-css-prefix}-style-family, "#{$fa-style-family}");`.
2. If you need duotone icons, clear the contents of `_duotone-icons.scss` and add this:

```
@each $name, $icon in $fa-icons {
  .#{$prefix}fad.#{$fa-css-prefix}-#{$name}::after,
  .#{$fa-css-prefix}-duotone.#{$fa-css-prefix}-#{$name}::after {
    content: unquote('"\#{$icon}\#{$icon}"') !important;
  }
}
```

3. Am not really sure in this step, maybe you can leave it out and perform only if it does not work without it. In `_functions.scss`, `_icons.scss`, `_mixins.scss` and `_shims.scss` there are lines like this: `@return unquote("\"#{ $fa-var }\"");`. In my current code all of these are transformed like: `@return unquote('"\#{ $fa-var }"');`. (The part `$fa-var` varies, especially in `_shims.scss`).
4. I had some problems with the `fa-divide` function in `_functions.scss`. The code here caused a stack overflow error. I actually filed a bug report to Font Awesome but I don't know whether it's fixed or not. I ended up with getting rid of the `fa-divide` function. This includes the following steps:

- In `_variables.scss` change every call to `fa-divide` to fixed values, like:

  - `fa-divide(20em, 16)` to `1.25em`
  - `$fa-li-width * fa-divide(5, 4)` to `2em`
- Remove `@import 'functions';` from all `scss` files.

5. Add this to `_variables.scss` (this is also because of the previous step, since it is originally in the `_functions.scss` file I decided to remove):

```
@function fa-content($fa-var) {
  @return unquote("#{ $fa-var }");
}
```

6. You might run into problems with older icon names that are no longer present in the installed FA, but you Ext JS code uses them. If you find something like this, you can add definitions to the end if `_variables.scss`, outside the closing `);`:

```
$fa-var-automobile: $fa-var-car;
```

7. If you have problems with imports during build, check for `@import` lines in the `scss` files, you might need to add a leading underscore, like `@import '_variables';` instead of `@import 'variables';`.
8. Finally, go through every font variation `scss` files you'd like to use (`fa-solid.scss` etc.), and make the following adjustments:

- Replace `content: unquote("\"#{ $icon }\"");` with `content: unquote('"\#{ $icon }"');`
- Overwrite `font-family` for the appropriate one, for example in `fa-light.scss` from `Font Awesome 6 Pro` to `Font Awesome 6 Pro Light`, in `fa-solid.scss` from `Font Awesome 6 Pro` to `Font Awesome 6 Pro Solid` etc.

When this is ready, **execute `sencha app build development`** to try it out.

You should be able to use icon variations in Ext JS code like:

```
x-fa fa-user
x-fal fa-user
x-fas fa-user
x-fat fa-user
x-fab fa-google
```

Please let me know how did it work out for you.

Comment: Thanks! I will let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

your post helped me a lot, Thanks. I just successfully integrated FA Pro 6.5.1 into Extjs 7.7, but I had to do some additional work...

Step 1:
In **_core.scss** fas, far, fal & fat points to the same font-family. I changed:

```
.fas,
.#{$fa-css-prefix}-classic,
.#{$fa-css-prefix}-solid,
.far,
.#{$fa-css-prefix}-regular,
.fal,
.#{$fa-css-prefix}-light,
.fat,
.#{$fa-css-prefix}-thin {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 6 Pro';
}
```

into

```
.fa, .x-fa, .x-far, .far,
.#{$fa-css-prefix}-regular {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 6 Pro Regular';
}
.x-fas, .fas,
.#{$fa-css-prefix}-classic,
.#{$fa-css-prefix}-solid {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 6 Pro Solid';
}
.fal,
.#{$fa-css-prefix}-light {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 6 Pro Light';
}
.fat,
.#{$fa-css-prefix}-thin {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 6 Pro Thin';
}
```

This change was required to use the different prefixes.

Step 2:
After running my App I noticed only the solid and regular fonts could be used.
In ext\packages\font-awesome\sass\src I updated the file **all.scss.** This file is used to build the final *.scss files. So I added the required missing fonts which my app needed:

```
@import "../etc/fa-solid.scss";  
@import "../etc/fa-light.scss";  
@import "../etc/fa-thin.scss";  
@import "../etc/fa-duotone.scss";
```

After running  **sencha app build development** (I mostly use **sencha app build -c development** to clear the current files) all the required fonts could be used.

I hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

Important addition.

Not al themes of Extjs work in the same way. After I thought I successfully integrated FA Pro 6.5.1 into Extjs 7.7 I noticed that not all standard icons were shown. Switching between several themes showed different results. So the integration of FA Pro 6.5.1 was NOT so successful as I thought. ☹
It toke some time to find the solution and solve it. Two issues:

- After running my App the final CSS still showed

  font: 16px/29px 'Material Icons', 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
- CSS-rules with pseudo-elements before and after show the content-value without the quotes

  .x-form-trigger-default:before {
  content: \f0d7;
  }

I’ll spare you the frustration of last week an show the solution. My App is most og the time using theme-material and for me the following steps solved the issues:

1. I seems Font Amewome 5 Free is hardcoded into Extjs

a)  Change ..\ext\classic\theme-neutral\sass\var\Componens.scss Font Awesome 5 Free into Font Awesome 6 Pro Solid

b)  Change ..\ext\classic\theme-material\sass\var\Componens.scss Font Awesome 5 Free into Font Awesome 6 Pro Solid

2. Open file ..\ext\classic\theme-neutral\sass\etc\mixins\font-icon.scss

Change the following line (2* :before and :after):

Change
`@include font-icon-pseudo-content($char, $rotation, $rotation-origin);`
into

```
@include font-icon-pseudo-content(unquote("\"\#{$char}\""), $rotation, $rotation-origin);
```

Now Extjs also show the correct default-icons.

Hope this helps

Comment: I skinned the cat differently ... I deployed the FA distribution on the web server and I referenced all the necessarily files in the same page that references all the ExtJs stuff. From there I simply search for the icons I need on the FA site, and copy their css classes and paste them in the iconCls property of the component and it all works

Comment: When I have time I will submit an answer with more details

Comment: always helpfull