# How to use Font Awesome 5.x Regular or Dualtone in Extjs 7.x

Tags: extjs, font-awesome, sencha-architect

I want to use Font Awesome 5.x with my upgraded Extjs application. (5.x to 7.x)
The icons are shown, but i cant change from solid to regular, light or duotone. Its always showing solid icons as it seems to be the default?

I tried:

```
x-fa far fa-arrow-circle-right -> solid icon shown
x-fa fa-arrow... -> solid icon shown
x-far fa-arrow... -> NO icon shown
far fa-arrow... -> NO icon shown
```

but the rotation works fine:
`x-fa fa-arrow-circle-right fa-rotate-90 -> solid icon, rotated 90 degree shown`

I have got the fa-brands, fa-regular and fa-solid files in resources/extjs-7.6.0.41/build/packages/font-awesome/resources/fonts

I appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Do you have the built-in Font Awesome package or you added it yourself?

Comment: Hello Peter, 
im using the built-in Font Awesome 5 which comes with extjs-7.6.0.41.

But i updatet by extjs 5.1 as the sencha support described.

Comment: For me the `x-fat fa-...` syntax works but I user FontAwesome Pro and added it myself. I am not sure about factory icons.

Comment: i tried a little more and this works: `x-far fa-file-excel` -> regular Icon,
but this wont show regular icon: `x-far fa-arrow-circle-right`

Comment: Try to search for the icon on FontAwesome website, they change icon names between versions. For example this one works? `x-far fa-circle-arrow-right`?

Comment: No this does not work (and its FA 6.x) 
Did you update manually to FA 6 or 5? 
Thanks for your time Peter!

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks again. 

Its confusing, not all icons in solid file are in regular file... Despite Font Awesome 5 showing everthing is convertible to regular on their own website. 
Either a function is not working in extjs (alas getting solid icons and build negatives of them = regular) or they are definitely not existent.

Comment: Yes I did. It is not en easy ride. I use 6 Pro.

Comment: When checking with https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/32tk (Ext JS 7.6.0 - Neptune) FA v4.4.0 get loaded from https://fiddle.sencha.com/classic/resources/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.4.0

Comment: I wrote an answer on this topic, although it is not accepted, maybe it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75631709/integrate-font-awesome-pro-5-with-extjs-7-6-0/75634863#75634863

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i manually updated to Font Awesome 6, everything is fine now.

Check out Peters Guide to upgrade FA here:
[Integrate font-awesome pro 5 with ExtJs 7.6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75631709/integrate-font-awesome-pro-5-with-extjs-7-6-0/75634863#75634863)